# Остановка первой формы через изменения значения combobox второй формы

Tags: c#

В общем есть 2 формы .Первая работает по умолчанию, надпись совершает движение вдоль границ.Требуется чтобы при смене значения во второй форме в combobox ,надпись из первой останавливалась и соответственно начинала двигаться при переключении значения обратно.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form1 form1;

    public Form2()

    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Что нужно написать тут?

    }


}
```

Ниже код первой

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    enum Direction { Right, Down, Left, Up };

    Direction direction = Direction.Right;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2 newForm = new Form2();

        newForm.Show();

    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (direction)

        { 
            case Direction.Right:
             label1.Left += 10;
                  break;

            case Direction.Down:
             label1.Top += 10;
                 break;

            case Direction.Left:
             label1.Left -= 10;
                 break;

            case Direction.Up:
             label1.Top -= 10;
                 break;
        }
            if (label1.Left > ClientRectangle.Width - label1.Width)
            {
            direction = Direction.Down;
            label1.Left = ClientRectangle.Width - label1.Width;

            }
            if (label1.Top > ClientRectangle.Height - label1.Height)
            {
            direction = Direction.Left;
            label1.Top = ClientRectangle.Height - label1.Height;
            }
            if (label1.Left < 0)
            {
            direction = Direction.Up;
            label1.Left = 0;

            }
            if (label1.Top < 0)
            {
            direction = Direction.Right;
            label1.Top = 0;
            }
        switch (direction)
        {
            case Direction.Right:
                label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(label1.Left * 255 / (ClientRectangle.Width - label1.Width), 0, 0);
                break;
            case Direction.Down:
                label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255, label1.Top * 255 / (ClientRectangle.Height - label1.Height), 0);
                break;
            case Direction.Left:
                label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(255 , 255, 255-(label1.Left * 255 / (ClientRectangle.Width - label1.Width)));
                break;
            case Direction.Up:
                label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(label1.Top * 255 / (ClientRectangle.Height - label1.Height), label1.Top * 255 / (ClientRectangle.Height - label1.Height), label1.Top * 255 / (ClientRectangle.Height - label1.Height));
                break;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Покажите код, которым вы сами пытались решить задачу и что конретно у вас не получилось?

Comment: Проблема в том ,что я только начал работать в VS и не понимаю ещё таких загвоздок как например вообще остановить первую программу второй и тем более через combobox.Код второй:
'public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form1 form1;
        
        public Form2()
            
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              //Что нужно написать тут?
         }
    }'

Comment: Сори за корявость ,не знаю как тут код правильно вставить

Comment: вставьте код в вопрос, в комментариях код просто нечитаем

Comment: @Алексей нажмите "править" и в редакторе все будет понятно (просто добавьте в вопрос)

Comment: а что вам нужно делать при выборе элемента комбобокса? вот это туда и пишите

Comment: представте еще код движения надписи, пожалуйста (`Form1`, как я понял)

Comment: Мне надо чтобы надпись в первой программе перестала двигаться ,а как это сделать я не знаю.

Comment: @Алексей ответ не помог?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    



        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
            form.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, v) => { 
                ComboBox c = o as ComboBox;
                button2.Text = c.Text;
            };
            form.Show();
        }
    }
```

чтобы comboBox стало видно нужно зайти в Form2.Designer и изменить уровень доступа на `public`.
Данный код меняет надпись на кнопке на `Form1`, в зависимости от выбора `comboBox` на `Form2`

Comment: Не правильно это с точки зрения ООП... По хорошему форма должна пробросить на ружу событие изменения ComboBox, а другая форма должна подписаться на изменение события.

Comment: @iluxa1810 предложите лучше, а просто коменты кидать и я умею). Я бы может тогда с вами согласился. А так даже не предполагаю как по другому сделать.

Comment: Унаследовать форму2 от 1 и комбобокс сделать протектед? Так будет лучше с т з ООП?

Comment: Я думаю, что нет. Самое верное решение- это сделать публичное событие с изменение текста. Если форма заинтересована в работе другой формы, то вторая форма на него подписывается и все.